# Not able to get transparent dropdown menu

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am building a website using flask-python, css, HTML.
I am not able to get transparent dropdown menu i changed the styling for css code and given proper code to HTML Layout.
The dropdown occurs in the center without any styling which i had speified in CSS styling
If i write the code in only in HTMl and CSS for dropdown menu.The drop down menu works perfectly fine.
Main python Script

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
import os
from flask import send_from_directory


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),
                               'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')

@app.route('/projects/')
def projects():
    return render_template("projects.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

layout code layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <body>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Developer | Krishan</title>
            <link rel = "stylesheet"  href ="{{ url_for('static' , filename = 'css/main.css') }}">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
        </head>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class = "logo">Krishan K B's Webpage</h1>
                <strong><nav>
                    <ul class = "menu">
                        <li><a href ="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="{{ url_for('projects') }}">Projects</a>
                            <ul class = "menu"> 
                                <li><a>Disaster Managment</a></li>
                                <li><a>Data Analytics</a></li>
                                <li><a>Volcanoes &amp; Population</a></li>
                                <li><a>Games</a></li>
                                <li><a>Book App</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>    
                    </ul>
                </nav></strong>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class = "container">
            {%block content%}
            {%endblock%}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Style css code style.css

```
body{
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:   brandon-grotesque,HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style : none;
}
ul li {
    float : left;
    width : 200px;
    height : 40px;
    background-color: #020202;
    opacity : .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color : white;
    display: block;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
}


h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Yellowtail', cursive;
  color: #e46922;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  font-size:60px;
}
h2{
  color:#66bfbf;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:'monntserrat',sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
h3{
  color: #11999e;
  font-family:'monntserrat',sans-serif;
}

p{
  line-height: 2;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 40px auto 60px;

}

hr{
  border: dotted #eaf6f6 6px;
  border-bottom: none;
  width: 6%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

a{
  color: #80b838;
  font-family:'monntserrat',sans-serif;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;

}
a:hover{
  color: #eaf6f6;
}
.head{
  color: #66bfbf;
  font-size: 140%;
}
.top{
  background-color: #E4F9F5;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;

}
.middle{
  margin: 100px 0;

}
.bottom{

  background-color: #66bfbf; ;
  padding: 50px 0 10px;


}
.intro{
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
}
.top-cloud{
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px;
  top: 30px;
}

.below-cloud{
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  bottom: 230px;
}
.img{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 320px;
}
.img-code{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 320px;
}
.skils{
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
}

.copyright{
  color: #eaf6f6;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
.contact-message{
  width: 40%;
  margin: 40px auto 60px;
}
.contact{
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.btn {
  margin: 100px;
  background: #45b29a;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #45b29a, #45b29a);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #45b29a, #45b29a);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #45b29a, #45b29a);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #45b29a, #45b29a);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #45b29a, #45b29a);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6;
  -moz-border-radius: 6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #1b7f69;
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #45b29a;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #45b29a, #1b7f69);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #45b29a, #1b7f69);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #45b29a, #1b7f69);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #45b29a, #1b7f69);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #45b29a, #1b7f69);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Output i received :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78fzz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your css is not properly rendered by flask, you need to [hard reload](https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/#:%7E:text=Hold%20down%20Ctrl%20and%20click,a%20menu%20will%20drop%20down.)

After this go to developers tool > sources tab , then search for the css file and crosscheck whether it is properly rendered or not.

Comment: remove the background color of the div with class top. then the navbar is visible

Comment: I removed the background-color of div class top it is displaying the menu but it is not functionable  i am not able to click the to go to any page The homepage menu is not working.

Comment: the problem is with the div with class home in home.html, that's the reason it covers the navbar, set the postition of container to relative and z-index to -1. position:relative; z-index:-1; this will bring the div to back and you can add background color now. Please mark this answer as correct if it solved the issue

Comment: Thanx its working perfectly fine now It was of great help

Answer (score 0):

Thanx i did hard reload and it worked but now i am not able to see the dropdown or any menu in my home page but i can see it in my projects webpage when i type /projects/ with the web address local host on URL. All the css styling changes are working perfectly fine but now there is no options menu in in my HomePage.
This is my homepage with no dropdown or any menu options to go to projects webpage :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHOVE.png)

This is my projects webpage, in this there is a dropdown and a menu with all the styling.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMeYs.png)

Homepage Code:

```
{%extends "layout.html"%}
{%block content%}
<div class = "home">
    <div class="top">
        <img class="top-cloud" src="{{ url_for('static' , filename = 'images/clo.png') }}" alt="cloud-img" height="200px">
        <h1> I'm Krishan.</h1>
        <p class="head">A Back End Developer.</p>
        <img class="below-cloud" src="{{ url_for('static' , filename = 'images/clo.png') }}" alt="cloud-img" height="200px">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static' , filename = 'images/land.svg') }}" alt="mounntains-img" height="350px">
    </div>

    <div class="middle">
        <img class="profile" src="{{ url_for('static' , filename = 'images/profile.png') }}" alt="profile" height="150px" >
            <h2>Hi.</h2>
                <P class="intro"> I'm a Programme developer,web developer and designer,UI Designer  based in Bangalore,India.I have a passion for web app,data analytics,web design,data analytics and coding and love to create new apps,website for web and mobile devices.</P>
    </div>
        <hr>
   <div>
        <h2>What I can do.</h2>
          <img class="img" src="{{ url_for('static' , filename = 'images/coding.png') }}" alt="" height="150px" >
            <p>I like to keep it simple. My goals is to develop a new programme which would be beneficial for the people and be enviromen friendly.</p>
   </div>

        <hr>
    <div class="skill">
          <h2>Develop what you need.</h2>
            <img class="img-code" src="{{ url_for('static' , filename = 'images/code-img.png') }}" alt="" height="150px" >
                <p class="skills">I'm a developer, so I know how to create your website,application or any other programme to run across devices using the latest technologies available.</p>
    </div>
        <hr>
    <div class="contact">
          <h2>Get in touch.</h2>
              <h3>I’m currently available for freelance work.</h3>
                  <p class="contact-message">if you have a project that you want to get started, think you need my help with something or just fancy saying hey, then get in touch.</p>
                    <a  class="btn" href="mailto:krishankbhushan@gmail.com">message me</a>
                  



    </div>
    </div>



    <div class="bottom">
        <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/krishan-k-b-0a164b125/">Linkedin</a><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                  <a class="fab fa-twitter" href=" https://twitter.com/krishankbhushan"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>Twitter</a>
                  <i class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size:24px"></i>
                      <p class="copyright">©️ 2021 Krishan.All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>

</div>
{%endblock%}
```